# makes me + adj and makes me feel + adj

Tags: grammar, difference

My student asked me why he should use "makes me feel + adj" when he can explain the same meaning by saying "it makes me + adj". But I doubt both are the same. Am I correct? And what is/are the distinction/s between these two?

Comment: Try to have him think about "It makes me feel good" with and without "feel".

Comment: @DamkerngT. witty suggestion, indicating the answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

When using an adjective that is specifically a feeling, like "excited" or "horrified," the meaning is essentially the same.

> - Skydiving makes me feel excited.
> - Skydiving makes me excited.

However, when using an non-feeling adjective, the meaning could be different. Take, for example, *invincible.*

> - When I'm with my lover, he makes me feel invincible.
> - When I'm with my lover, he makes me invincible.

In this case, *he makes me feel* is correct. It's unlikely that your lover literally imbues you with immortality or superhuman strength.

Answer (score 2):

It's a battle between what 'you feel' **and** 'what (actually) you are'.

If something makes you *feel*, it could be psychological. On the other hand, if something makes you something, it's the fact you are talking about.

As Damkerng pointed it out very well, these two examples are completely different

> It makes me feel good 
>  It makes me good

Do you see the difference? The former one is psychological.